# When was the tzitz lost?

Tags: history

I was reading a translation of Josephus many years ago that mentioned the tzitz (the crown of the high priest with Qdosh Yisrael engraved on it). The commentary to this Josephus said that the tzitz was written in Paleo Hebrew and this had been confirmed because the tzitz had only gotten lost much later after the destruction of the temple and so people had written descriptions of it.

Unfortunately I don't have access to this Josephus anymore, and I have tried googling to find out when the tzitz was lost and where it was being kept but I can't find any information. Does anyone here have any knowledge? Obviously if the tzitz was written in Paleo it would have religious significance.

Comment: Check the Schottentstein Mas. Kiddushin 5a2, note 23 which implies (or at least, I infer) that there was more than one tzitz. Which one did you mean?

Comment: As @rosends said, my understanding is only the aron is unique.  For the other vessels, we can just make new ones as needed, and I assume that's what was done.

Comment: So maybe we can ask, when was the LAST tzitz lost?

Comment: I wonder if the tzitz has to be written in a specific script or language.  The [Rambam](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Vessels_of_the_Sanctuary_and_Those_who_Serve_Therein.9.1-2) doesn't say anything about that [like he does for Sta"m](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Tefillin%2C_Mezuzah_and_the_Torah_Scroll.1.19), and there's some flexibility to the arrangement of the words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you were reading was the English translation of the complete works of Josephus by [William Whiston](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Whiston). It was published by Kregel Publications in 1960 and the last edition in 1984.

Whiston’s translation was published by William P. Nimmo of Edinburgh, Scotland in 1867.

The footnote you remember was in Antiquities of the Jews, book 3, chapter 7:6.

Whiston makes the claim that the Tzitz was written in Samaritan script (the script used by the Shomronim in their holy writings.)

Checking the citations he points to in Josephus along with several other places in Josephus’ writings (for example Wars of the Jews, book 5, chapter 5:7, and Against Apion, book 2:8), do not confirm his claim. Whiston also points to Origen as an outside source for this statement.

I have not checked what is left of Origen to see if it makes that claim.

It is worth noting that both the footnote and the Torah say what was written on the Tzitz was, “Holy to G-d”.

Concerning the Tzitz itself, the one made at the time of Moshe Rabbeinu was hidden by Yirmiyahu HaNavi before the destruction of the first Temple like is recorded in the [Copper Scroll](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper_Scroll) discovered at Qumran in 1952 and as independently recorded in Sefer Emek HaMelech by Rabbi Naftali Bacharach which was published in 5408 (1648) in the 3rd introduction, chapter 11, Mishnah 1.

Comment: [The footnote](http://earlyjewishwritings.com/text/josephus/ant3.html#EndNote_ANT_3.14b) you refer to says "See Antiq. B. VIII. ch. 3. sect. 8" Josephus says [there](http://earlyjewishwritings.com/text/josephus/ant8.html#EndNote_ANT_8.12a) as promised: "But the crown upon which Moses wrote [the name of God], was only one, and *hath remained to this very day*." The point about it being in ketav ivri is presumably mentioned in the other sources he quotes. (Also: Whiston translated from Greek, not from Latin; he was published long before 1960; and Nimmo is a publisher, not an earlier translator.)

Comment: @ba Sorry for misreading the paragraph on the back of the title page. I will correct the comment about Nimmo. What threw me off was that it says the 1984 edition is a combination. The Whiston translation was published by Nimmo in 1867. The 1984 edition was combined with the Porter & Coates standard edition. Josephus mentions the Tzitz not only Antiquities B, but also Antiquities of the Jews, book 3, chapter 7:6, and Wars of the Jews, book 5, chapter 5:7 which says G-d’s name is 4 vowels! None of the citations from Josephus mention Samaritan script or paleo-Hebrew.

Comment: Finally getting somewhere. Thank you! Although I'd love to find the source in Origen

Comment: Where in the Copper scroll is it mentioned?

Comment: @Gary The text of the Copper Scroll follows the text of Sefer Emek HaMelech. It is the very first Mishnah which begins with the words, “אלו הן הכלים המקודשים והגנוזים כשחרב בית המקדש כו׳”

Comment: @Gary The opening words to chapter 11 listing the names of the 5 individuals who were actually instructed by Yirmiyahu to hide the vessels were actually engraved on a marble cover that was on top of the clay container which held the Copper Scroll. That marble cover is in the Antiquities Museum in Jordan today.

Comment: Sounds legendary. I don't know where the object in Jordan was found, but all archaeological sources say the Copper Scroll was found naked by itself, in two pieces, some write on a low shelf, in a separate area of cave 3 from where its other scrolls were found.  Absolutely positively not found in a container of any sort.

Comment: All translations I've seen have "vessels of contribution" etc and "priestly vestments" listed for some locations, but never the tzitz.  If you have a Hebrew transcription of it that says it, please let me know where/which location it's mentioned as being buried at.

Comment: @Gary You are mistaken. The Copper Scroll was in a clay container and filled with dirt. The marble cover was on top of the clay container. Jordan had jurisdiction of the area back in 1952. I used to correspond with Vendyl Jones who relayed all this archeological history to me. It’s not myth. It is real.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97913/discussion-between-gary-and-yaacov-deane).

Comment: Here are Whiston's sources: [Essay on the Old Test. p. 154](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=y45AAAAAcAAJ&hl=iw&pg=PA154#v=onepage&q&f=false) (English) and [Reland p. 132](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=KZxhAAAAcAAJ&lpg=PA4&dq=Relandi%20de%20spoliis%20templi%20Hierosolymitani&hl=iw&pg=PA132#v=onepage&q=Relandi%20de%20spoliis%20templi%20Hierosolymitani&f=false) (Latin)

Comment: The former quotes Origen from "Monfauc. Hexapl. in Anecdot. Orig. p. 86" which I couldn't find, but I did find [this](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=EpVhAAAAcAAJ&lpg=PA231&dq=anecdot.%20origen.&hl=iw&pg=PA233#v=onepage&q=anecdot.%20origen.&f=false) book (a polemic against Whiston's book) which quotes Origen in Greek with English translation, but disputes that it's a genuine quote. In any case this passage from Origen isn't in the online Thesaurus Linguae Graecae (no relevant results for ἀνεκφώνητον). @Aaron

Comment: @ba - I wouldn't trust Whiston too far- IIRC, there's an obviously xtian essay that he tries to prove was written by Josephus after he joined their church. And he also writes a bit trying ro prove the yeshu passage is absolutely genuine. Obviously never ran across the Arabic Josephus version that Shlomo Pines found..

Comment: @Gary I don't trust his esoteric speculations but I would trust his quotations. Though in this case the quotation seems suspicious for other reasons

Comment: @ba I haven’t forgotten your request to see the connection between Sefer Emek HaMelech & the text of the Copper Scroll. I simply haven’t had time yet to pull it together. But the relevant portion in the Copper Scroll is primarily columns 5-7. That identifies the inventory of hidden objects to include garments of the Kohen Gadol & vessels from the Mishkan especially the קלל which contains the ashes of the red heifer made by Moshe Rabbeinu. Regarding the קלל, see Mishnah Parah 3:3, among many other sources.